# Why add and remove function is not working at the same time in a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have started learning JS recently and am stuck here. I have created a dice game where images change themselves randomly when a button is clicked.

The images just get changed from one to another. I want to give a rolling effect to them. So, I have added animation for them that they change angles in both X-axis and Y-axis. It works on the first click but later doesn't.

So I had added `classList.add()` to give the animation and `classList.remove()` to remove but the remove function doesn't work.

This is HTML code:

```js
function roll() {
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].classList.add("rollEffect");
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].classList.add("rollEffect");
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var randomImage1 = "dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png";
  var randomImage2 = "dice" + randomNumber2 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src", randomImage1);
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src", randomImage2);

  if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2)
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player1 wins!!!";
  else
  if (randomNumber2 > randomNumber1)
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player2 wins!!!";
  else
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "DRAW!!!";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].classList.remove("rollEffect");
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].classList.remove("rollEffect");
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #8843F2;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding: 1% 2%;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.dice {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes rollClick {
  9% {
    transform: rotateX(30deg) rotateY(30deg)
  }
  18% {
    transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(60deg)
  }
  28% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(90deg)
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateY(120deg)
  }
  46% {
    transform: rotateX(150deg) rotateY(150deg)
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg)
  }
  65% {
    transform: rotateX(210deg) rotateY(210deg)
  }
  76% {
    transform: rotateX(240deg) rotateY(240deg)
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(270deg)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(300deg) rotateY(300deg)
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotateX(330deg) rotateY(330deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg)
  }
}

.rollEffect {
  animation-name: rollClick;
  animation-duration: 0.1s;
}

body {
  background-color: #F9D371;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Roll us</h1>
  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 1</p>
    <img class="img1" src="dice6.png">
  </div>
  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 2</p>
    <img class="img2" src="dice6.png">
  </div>
  <button class="btn" onclick="roll()">Roll</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: When trying your code, there is an error that `rollAnimation` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to remove that function call.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript code that adds the rolling animation class runs separate from any animation durations.

It will run as quickly as the performance of the device allows.

In your js code it will:

1. add the `.rollEffect` class to both images.
2. set a new image url.
3. set text with the result of the game
4. remove the `.rollEffect` class from both images.

This all happens as fast as possible, we're talking micro/nano seconds.
So the animation does get applied, each time, and gets removed each time. so fast you can't even see the animation.

**You have to wait a bit before removing the animation class. so the animation has time to run before it's removed.**

This can be achived with [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
For example:

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].classList.remove("rollEffect");
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].classList.remove("rollEffect");
  }, 100); // <--- 100 here will execute the code in the callback after 100ms, the same as the animation time.
```

```js
function roll() {
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].classList.add("rollEffect");
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].classList.add("rollEffect");
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var randomImage1 = `http://placekitten.com/g/${50*randomNumber1}/300`;
  var randomImage2 = `http://placekitten.com/g/200/${50*randomNumber2}`;
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src", randomImage1);
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src", randomImage2);

  if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2)
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player1 wins!!!";
  else
  if (randomNumber2 > randomNumber1)
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player2 wins!!!";
  else
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "DRAW!!!";

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].classList.remove("rollEffect");
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].classList.remove("rollEffect");
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #8843F2;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding: 1% 2%;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.dice {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes rollClick {
  9% {
    transform: rotateX(30deg) rotateY(30deg)
  }
  18% {
    transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(60deg)
  }
  28% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(90deg)
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateY(120deg)
  }
  46% {
    transform: rotateX(150deg) rotateY(150deg)
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg)
  }
  65% {
    transform: rotateX(210deg) rotateY(210deg)
  }
  76% {
    transform: rotateX(240deg) rotateY(240deg)
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(270deg)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(300deg) rotateY(300deg)
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotateX(330deg) rotateY(330deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg)
  }
}

.rollEffect {
  animation-name: rollClick;
  animation-duration: 0.1s;
}

body {
  background-color: #F9D371;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Roll us</h1>
  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 1</p>
    <img class="img1" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 2</p>
    <img class="img2" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
  </div>
  <button class="btn" onclick="roll()">Roll</button>
</div>
```